# FilePath macro does not contain value in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, pycharm, python-black

I have installed the `Python Black` code formatter (https://github.com/psf/black). I want to integrate it into my `PyCharm` as an external tool.
I have added the arguments of `Black` but the `$FilePath$` macro does not provide the path of current file.

**My current config:**

```
Settings > Tools > External Tools > Black

Program: /home/milanbalazs/.local/bin/black
Arguments: --fast -l 100 -v $FilePath$
Working directory: /home/milanbalazs/.local/bin
```

**Output of Black when I run it:**

```
/home/milanbalazs/.local/bin/black --fast -l 100 -v
No paths given. Nothing to do 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see above the `$FilePath$` macro does not provide the path of file. But when I check it in the `Insert Macro...` option then it provides the correct path in the `Macro preview` box.

Any idea how can I solve it or what can be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a file in focus while invoking the external tool?

Comment: WoW, You are right. If the `code editor` window is not in focus or something in the `project view` window the `$FilePath$` macro doesn't provide the path of file. On the other hand if something is selected in the `project view` window, the macro proved the path of that file/dir. It is strange for me. Is it a bug or a feature? :) If you write your comment as an answer, I will mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's a feature. `$FilePath$` (and other similar macros) requires a file to be selected either in the editor or in the project tree.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I have been thinking about this feature and now it seems logic! :)